# Limit number of edits on a newly posted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

**Scenario:**

A new question is posted. Within 30 seconds of posting, there is a answer with a bare minimal/incomplete solution. Over the next two minutes, 5-6 edits are made to the answer, with each edit gradually adding to/improving the answer.

**Problem:**

Users rush to have their answers posted first to gain (possible)upvotes, rather than focusing on the quality and content of the answer. Need to frequently click the reload link to see what new content has been added.

You see an answer, find it incomplete, proceed to write your own, then find your solution has been added by the first guy in his rapid successive edits.

**Proposed solution:**

Limit number of times a newly posted answer can be edited. Like e.g. only two edits are allowed for the first five minutes after posting an answer.

Comment: related, if not a dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: @MandeepJain Disagreement with our proposal

Comment: I would negatively be impacted by this. I often edit my answers after posting to include extra links to documentation. Also I don't understand how limiting the edit options improves the overall post quality for the OP and future visitors. Your feature will sacrifice short term quality of answers in favor of your own  answer, assuming you are capable of posting an answer that doesn't need edits directly after posting. I don't think the FGITW is a problem that needs to be addressed and if it needs to be addressed then please don't do it by limiting edits.

Comment: @rene As I said, one or two edits are fine. You can add extra stuff. My main objective here is that answers are well informed when they are posted to avoid the fastest gun problem you mentioned in the comment above

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sorry but didnt understand you

Comment: My main objective is to get answers into good shape, no matter how many edits it takes and in which timeframe.

Comment: This wouldn't even solve the problem you claim to have.  If you succeeded in stopping this user from making edits, and forced them to finish their answer before posting it, then you'd simply see no answer, start writing your own, and then have that user post their finished answer before you finish yours, still resulting in the same end situation where you spent time writing an answer at the same time someone else was writing theirs.

Comment: What @PatrickHofman meant to say is that the down votes indicate that the voters disagree with **your** proposal: "*Limit number of times a newly posted answer can be edited.*". Their votes indicate that they don't want the development team to implement this feature.

Comment: the way to proceed is [explained here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601)

Comment: @rene Ok. Got it

Answer (score 4):

If you see an answer which comprises "a bare minimal/incomplete solution" then I think you would be justified to apply a downvote to it on the grounds that in its current state it is not useful.

Comment: The user states they are answering that same question. What you propose can be seen as tactical down voting. Not sure what is worse, FGITW or the tactical down vote

Comment: Especially when you don't remove that down-vote when the answer is substantially improved...

Comment: @rene Downvoting a post because it's not useful is not tactical voting.  It's using voting correctly.  Tactical downvoting is downvoting a post *that you think is useful* because you want your answer to be shown above it.

Comment: @Snow People are not obligated to go back and revisit every post they ever vote on any time they're edited.  If the person is worried about downvotes on their answer, they shouldn't be posting incomplete and unhelpful answers to questions.